# Can you change a python descriptor's __get__ method at runtime?

Tags: python, decorator, descriptor

All,
   As the title asks, is it possible to change the `__get__` method of a Descriptor at run time.  I'm in a situation where I've got a function that is being decorated and undecorated on the the fly at run time.  I'd like the result of this function to be available as a attribute, similar to what the `@property` does.  I researched that and found it's a descriptor, but it seems descriptors' `__get__` method is read only.

```
class Test( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self._x = 10

    def get_x( self ):
        return self._x

    @property
    def x( self ):
        return self.get_x()
```

The above code does what I want, roughly, in that

1. The value is set in the constructor
2. I can decorate the `get_x` method to my heart's content
3. `instance.x` returns the correct value

My issue is that I'd rather not have to create the `get_x` method since it's basically unnecessary.  I just haven't been able to decorate the `__get__` method of x as it is read-only.

**Background**

I'm writing a turn based strategy game, and I'm using decorators to implement persistent conditions.  I'm able to implement these decorators effectively when I use test cases, but the issue is that to get the computed value then, you must use a function call, not an attribute access.  This seems like an bad idea because getting values describing a unit would inconsistently use functions or attributes.  I'd like to standardize on attributes if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override default "read-only" characteristic of `property`'s `__get__` attribute using simple inheritance :

```
class MyProperty( property ): pass

class Test( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self._x = 10

    def get_x( self ):
        return self._x

    @MyProperty
    def x( self ):
        return self.get_x()

test = Test()
```

The problem now that even if you redefine `__get__` attribure of your Text.x property, on `test.x` request python runtime will call `MyProperty.__get__(Test.x, test, Test)`

So you could rewrite it only there like

```
MyProperty.__get__ = lambda self,instance,owner: ""the x attribute"
```

So good option here is to delegate call to some redifineable attribute like

```
MyProperty.__get__ = lambda self,instance,owner: self.get(instance,owner)
```

From now on **get** attribute of your property in your full  control.
Also there is bad option to generate separate type for each property-like object.
So in good case you could do something like:

```
class MyProperty( property ):
    def __get__(self,instance,owner) :
        if not instance: return self
        else: return self.get(instance,owner)

class Test( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self._x = 10

    def get_x( self ):
        return self._x

    @MyProperty
    def x( self ): pass

    @MyProperty
    def y(self): pass

    x.get = lambda self,clazz: self.get_x()
    y.get = lambda self,clazz: "the y property of " + clazz.__name__ + " object"

>>> test = Test()
>>> test.x
10
>>> test.y
'the y property of Test object'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this this evening, but it looks like it does what I want.  If everything works I'll accept the answer.